# How to separate space and semicolon in CSV files import to MS Access?

Tags: csv, ms-access, ms-access-2010, delimited

Here is my sample CSV file:

```
2000-01-10 19:59;0.000;m3/h;100.9;-0.0;100.9;m3;0.000;0.000;99;66
2000-01-10 20:14;0.000;m3/h;100.9;-0.0;100.9;m3;0.000;0.000;99;66
2000-01-10 20:29;0.000;m3/h;100.9;-0.0;100.9;m3;0.000;0.000;99;66
2000-01-10 20:44;0.000;m3/h;100.9;-0.0;100.9;m3;0.000;0.000;99;66
2000-01-10 20:59;0.000;m3/h;100.9;-0.0;100.9;m3;0.000;0.000;99;66
2000-01-10 21:14;0.000;m3/h;100.9;-0.0;100.9;m3;0.000;0.000;99;66
```

I have a problem separating the date and time. In delimited I can only choose semicolon. I can only choose one.

How can I separate all of them?

Comment: replace spaces with semicolons?

Comment: How are you uploading the CSV?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the delimiter.

Select *Delimiter* to *None*.

Select *Separator* to *;*

Then import/link as DateTime and split this (if you really have to).

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the first space in each line of the CSV file by a semicolon using a small batch file to have date and time as separate field values if this is required for the database before importing the CSV file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Define CSV file to process which can be also passed as argument
rem and the temporary file needed while processing the CSV file.
if "%~1" == "" (
    set "CSV_File=C:\Temp\Test.csv"
    set "TempFile=%TEMP%\Test.tmp"
) else (
    set "CSV_File=%~1"
    set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n1.tmp"
)

rem Check existence of CSV file to process and if really existing,
rem write each line of CSV file to temporary file with replacing
rem the first space by a semicolon. After having processed each
rem line move the temporary file over the CSV file.

if exist "%CSV_File%" (
    if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"
    for /F "usebackq eol=# tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ("%CSV_File%") do echo %%A;%%B>>"%TempFile%"
    move /Y "%TempFile%" "%CSV_File%"
)

endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... for an explanation of `%~1` and `%~n1`.
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) might be also interesting to understand redirection operator `>>` used in this little batch code.